# push text input to array with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am setting up a temporary array to let users try and edit a few things and I'm trying to save a text input value to the arrary. The current method I am using is pushing something but it's showing up as a blank. I'm thinking I am not really getting the value from the text input correctly, have a look and see-

Here's the button and input

```
<input type="text" ng-module="tagName"><button type="button" class="resultsButton" ng-click="addTag()">Submit</button>
```

In my controller -

```
 $scope.tagsFeed = ["one", "two", "thre", "four", "five", "six"];

//ignore delete function
            $scope.deleteTag = function($index){
                $scope.tagsFeed.splice($index,1);
            };

            $scope.addTag = function(){

                $scope.tagsFeed.push($scope.tagName);
            };
```

My add tag function however does not seem to be working correctly. Pushing the button adds a blank entry to the array, I tried to console.log $scope.tagName and it seems to come abck as undefined. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: did you mean `ng-model` ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think you want `ng-model` instead of `ng-module`.

So change

```
<input type="text" ng-module="tagName">
```

To this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="tagName">
```

Comment: Happens to the best of us =D